# Can't get values from acceleration sensor android after turn off the screen

Tags: android

Android version 2.2+

Is there any way that I can still get the values from the acceleration sensor even after the screen is turned off (I already made my program as an activity)? When the screen-on is timeout, I will release the wake lock that I used to wake up the phone (to turn the screen on)

Note: When I tried my program in the debugging mode (connected to my computer), it worked fine.

P/s: There is one funny thing, when I tried my program on my sony arc s (stock rom 2.3.4), it stopped sending values from acc sensor after about 10 minutes, but in my friend's phone, he uses cooked rom Cyanogenmod 7, it stopped sending immediately after the screen had turned off. This made me wonder that would android have shallow sleep mode and deep sleep mode. I assumed that in shallow sleep mode, all activities would be able to run normally, but in deep sleep mode, only system activities could run. Am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: i wonder if we can simulate the debugging mode on android or not, this may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice writeup of the issue, it's quite common.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/04/monitoring-sensors-in-background.html

and an official bug report:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708

[Corrected:]

The bug report is closed, so I guess it works in the latest and greatest versions of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about sleep mode on android.
But try to take a look at Activity's life-cycle

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

It could give you clues about which state is your app, and do what's necessary to prevent loss of data.
IMO, when screen turn off, i think user's apps go in "onPause" state